# node_redis : using client.multi within forEach

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I have the following code that should retrive the list of devices and get the status and label for each of them:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
  db.smembers("devices", function(err1, devices){
    var jsonObj = {};
    if(!err1) {
       var i = 0;
       devices.forEach(function(id){
          db.multi([
             ["get", id + ":label"],
             ["get", id + ":status"],
          ]).exec(function (err, replies) {
             jsonObj[id] = {"label":replies[0], "status":replies[1]};
             console.log(jsonObj);     // stuff is added on each loop
          });

          i = i + 1;
          if(i == devices.length){  
             console.log(jsonObj);     // jsonObj is {}     
             h.respond(res, jsonObj);
          }
       });
    } else {
       h.respond(res, { "error" : err1 });
    }
  });
});
```

devices is a list of ids. For each id, there are 2 keys: "ID:status", "ID:label"

h.respond is an helper method that sends the http response.

I can see the new data being added to the jsonObj on each loop, but when all the loop are done, it's empty.

Comment: Had a similar problem. Good quesion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is running asynchronously and is counting up to devices.length before any of the Redis calls actually completes (it doesn't wait for the callbacks from `multi` to return before continuing). Moving your check into the callback will prevent this.

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
  db.smembers("devices", function(err1, devices){
    var jsonObj = {};
    if(!err1) {
       var i = 0;
       devices.forEach(function(id){
          db.multi([
             ["get", id + ":label"],
             ["get", id + ":status"],
          ]).exec(function (err, replies) {
             jsonObj[id] = {"label":replies[0], "status":replies[1]};
             console.log(jsonObj);     // stuff is added on each loop
             i = i + 1;
             if(i == devices.length){  
                console.log(jsonObj);     // jsonObj is {}     
                h.respond(res, jsonObj);
             }
          });


       });
    } else {
       h.respond(res, { "error" : err1 });
    }
  });
});
```

Probably make more sense to move this code into a separate function, but hopefully you get the idea. An async library like `async` provides helper methods that make it much easier to do parallel async loops like this.

Comment: I was not at the rigth callback level then, thanks a lot that's working fine now !

Comment: Nicely spotted! I second the recommendation for [async](https://github.com/caolan/async). I can't recommend this library enough, it really helps to clean up this kind of flow control with a minimum of added complexity.